# Are all of the numbers in my file legitimate hex numbers

Tags: string-manipulation, regular-expressions

I have about 10,000 hexadecimal numbers (32 digits each) in an excel file, in one column.  I want to verify that all of them are indeed hexadecimal number and that no other characters are present.  My first thought was to import them into a list and then apply 16^^# to the list and see if I get any errors.  This doesn't seem to work because the import is bringing them in as strings. I can't figure out how to convert the strings to something that 16^^ will work on.  Is there something I can do?

Another approach, which I didn't try would be using regular expressions to validate that only proper characters are in each number.  I almost never use regular expressions, so a hint along those lines would be helpful.

If there's a better approach I would love to hear it.

I'm using Windows 7, Mathematica 10.0.2.0, Excel 10.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Mac/Linux?

Comment: @2012rcampion I'm using Windows 7.  I just added that to my original question.

Comment: Assuming the "characters" in the imported strings are just the standard hex, StringMatchQ[#, Characters["0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfF"] ..] & /@myimportedstrings will give the vector of good/bad, and And @@ (StringMatchQ[#, 
     Characters["0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfF"] ..] & /@ myimportedstrings) will give a go/no go for whole set.

Comment: If you're doing most of your processing in Excel, try using `ISERROR(HEX2DEC(cell))`.  If you're importing into Mathematica anyway, use one of the `StringMatchQ[#,HexadecimalCharacter..]&` solutions below.

Comment: @2012rcampion I tried HEX2DEC, but my probable Hex numbers were too long.  Thanks.

Comment: @rasher Thanks, that works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `StringMatchQ` and `HexadecimalCharacter` to check the list for non-hex items.

First I'll make some hexadecimal strings and insert some non-hex ones.

```
hexStrings = IntegerString[RandomInteger[{10, 30000}, 100], 16];
AppendTo[hexStrings, "zxc2"]; PrependTo[hexStrings, "x34c"];
```

Now we can `Map` the `StringMatchQ` function over the list using a `Repeated` pattern of `HexadecimalCharacter`. The operator form of `Position` is then applied to this result to get the `False` matches.  Finally it is `Flatten`ed to get a flat list of these positions.

```
Flatten@
  Position[False]@(StringMatchQ[#, HexadecimalCharacter ..] & /@ hexStrings)
```

This will return the positions of any non-hex strings in the list or an empty list if all strings are hexadecimal.  Once you have the positions you can use other functions to manage the non-hex strings.

Hope this helps.